# Certificate SAN Mismatch. The (SAN) of SSL certificate does not appear to match the host address.

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, ssl-certificate, exchange-2007

Server Enviroment:
Exch2003 (recently Decommissioned)
Exch2007 (Will be decommissioned as soon as 2010 is up and going)
Exch2007#2
Exch2010 (In process of installing)

So I am at the point of installing exchange 2010 where I need to run the pre-deployment analyzer on my Exchange 2007 servers to make sure everything is working good. When I run the health check I have gotten the following error.

Certificate SAN Mismatch Server: EXCH2007

The subject alternative name (SAN) of SSL certificate for https://owa.*domain*.org/owa does not appear to match the host address. Host address: owa.*domain*.org. Current SAN: DNS Name=EXCH2007#2, DNS Name=EXCH2007#2.heartspring.org.

The error is coming from the Exch2007 server that I am going to be decommissioning as soon as Exch2010 is good to go. So at this time there are actually no user mailboxes on the machine. Everything has been moved to the second EXCH2007#2 server.

So, since this server is going to be decommissioned eventually is this something I can ignore and continue with the setup of Exchange2010?

To resolve this would I need to issue a new certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already able to migrate mailboxes, then don't worry about it unless it's causing an issue.  If the owa.domain.org cert doesn't have the old server FQDN data and all of the public namespaces, then you'll get these errors.

The analyzer may also error due to NETBIOS names in the cert since that's no longer supported from a CA perspective, so the tool maybe geared towards current requirements and not what existed when 2007 was out.

Else, we'd need to know URL strings, and the SAN cert details so we could see what may be missing.... but like prior stated, if it's not causing an issue with the migration, ignore and drop that 2007 like a bad habit.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no mailboxes on the server at all, then I would just change all of the URLs to match the Exchange 2010 server. That way Autodiscover will return the correct information no matter what. 
Although in the main it isn't an issue, other than for internal Autodiscover, which you should probably change to match the trusted SSL certificate on the new server.

Comment: Good to see you here, Simon.